# Telethon does not connect via proxy on behalf of the client

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, telethon

I have such a problem: telethon cannot connect to a telegram through a proxy (I checked it through account sessions (there was an ip from which the python project was launched)) I did everything on the new docks and the proxy was also one hundred percent working (I was not very good at python. all according to the pattern) Sorry for the translation) Here is the part of the code where the client is created:

```
client = TelegramClient("session/" + phone_number,
             api_id, api_hash,
             proxy=(socks.HTTP, proxy, port, login, password))
client.connect()
```

Then checking the session

```
if not client.is_user_authorized():

    try:
        client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input("\n\n\n\033[1;0mEnter Your Code : "))

    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        passw = input("\033[1;0mYour 2fa Password : ")
        me = client.start(phone_number, passw)

myself = client.get_me()
```

I will be glad to help

Comment: Maybe you can help? https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1503

Comment: @Lonami Thank you! This helped me he now sees the proxy does not ignore him. Only now we get another error: gaierror: `[Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about proxies, but you're free to help in the issue.